# Pandas - how to flag if a dataframe column has a non-permitted value in it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
offer | type
------|-----
123   | A
456   | B
789   | C
```

I want to set up an if statement which prints a warning message if any values other than A or B are included in the type column. The values can be in upper or lower case, but should only be A or B.

I've tried using the code below, but it doesn't work - it returns the message saying everything is ok regardless of whether there are other types in the type column:

```
if ~df["type"].isin(["A","B","a","b"]).any():
    print("WARNING - Not all offers are the correct types!")
else:
    print("OK - All offers are the correct types.")
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Logically you should use `all()` instead of `any()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72940924/9769953) is the better solution, but to show where your method went wrong:

```
if (~df["type"].isin(["A","B","a","b"])).any():
    print("WARNING - Not all offers are the correct types!")
else:
    print("OK - All offers are the correct types.")
```

will work correctly.

Note the extra parentheses around `~df["type"].isin(["A","B","a","b"])`. Because that is the expression that you want to check for any `True` value, but `.any()` in your expression applies to `df["type"].isin(["A","B","a","b"])`. So your statement is equivalent to

```
~(df["type"].isin(["A","B","a","b"])).any()
```

Thus, the negation happens *after* `.any()` is applied, in your case. In my solution above, the negation happens before that `.any()` is applied.

This is basically a case of operator precedence, or what operator binds more tightly (the `.` for the method call binds more tightly here than the negation operator `~`).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(list('ABC'), columns=['type'])
# logic using .all()
if df['type'].isin(list('ABab')).all():
    print("OK - All offers are the correct types.") 
else:
    print("WARNING - Not all offers are the correct types!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you
if any one of the values in the Type column is not in `['A', 'B', 'a', 'b']`, should print a warning as I understand it. And use `all()` instead of `any()`

```
if ~(df['type'].isin(['A', 'B', 'a', 'b'])).all():
    print('warning')
else:
    print('ok')
```